# При запуске прилоежния Too many open files

Tags: java

При запуске jettyHttpclient выходит ошибка java.io.IOException: Too many open     files

думаю проблема не в jetty, а в том что открыто много файлов и не закрыто, ни где в приложении не открываются файлы, как можно отследить и узнать кто их открывает на Linuxe

как решить эту проблему, у меня открытых файлов программой 1300 из них 1000 Это pipe и anon_inode, что это и для чего кто их должен закрывать

```
09-06-2016 11:54:19.281 MSK|WARN |WebContainer :     1|org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle|FAILED     org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient@9385cdee: java.io.IOException: Too many open     files
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:78) ~[na:1.7.0]
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:49) ~[na:1.7.0]
            at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:239) ~[na:1.7.0]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.<init>(SelectorManager.java:416) ~[jetty-io-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:261) ~[jetty-io-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81) ~[jetty-util-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81) ~[jetty-util-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:433) ~[jetty-client-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.15.v20140411.jar:7.6.15.v20140411]
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: В линуксе команда lsof -p <pid> выведет вам файлы, открытые вашим приложением.

Comment: Из личной практики не чтения документации недавно сам столкнулся с проблемой, Files.list из java.nio возвращает стрим, который необходимо закрывать :)

Comment: спасибо запустил, он действительно открывает больше 1024 файлов и там много pipe и anon_inode, нормально ли это?
java    56802 root 1013u   REG                0,9        0      4032 anon_inode
java    56802 root 1014w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 737164753 pipe
java    56802 root 1015u   REG                0,9        0      4032 anon_inode
java    56802 root 1016r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 737164754 pipe
java    56802 root 1017w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 737164754 pipe

Comment: ну смотря что делает ваше приложение. если используете в качестве IDE IntellijIdea, попробуйте запустить статический анализатор кода встроенный: меню Analyze -> Inspect Code. Он должен показать незакрытые ресурсы, если таковы имеются.

Comment: нормально ли то что соединения с сайтом остаются, и не отключается даже спустя день,
java    56802 root  978u  IPv6          737147238      0t0       TCP urf-corce-048.ca.ferten.ru:60151->urf-corce-008.ca.ferten.ru:ncube-lm (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: нет, конечно не нормально, нужно их закрывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию дается возможность открыть 1024 файловых дескриптора (в том числе и сокетов). Но если сильно хочется, можно "подкрутить параметры" - `ulimit -n <нужное-кол-во>`. Правда запускать нужно от имени рута.

Но это не исправление ошибки, а "сокрытие".

Но так как это java, то хоть и  гарантируют, что объекты будут уничтожены, но никто не гарантирует когда. Поэтому, если хотите, что бы все было правильно - самостоятельно освобождайте ресурсы, которые Вы захватываете. Либо переходите на нормальные языки, где есть RAII и все работает "из-коробки".

По ссылке ниже есть разбор похожего примера, где вызывают закрытие потока.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656458/java-net-socketexception-too-many-open-files